# MoSKito monitor: why does the value not autoreload?

Tags: monitor

I have deployed MoSKito stand-alone web application to monitor my own web. 
I'm able to view thread, memory, time... as I expect. 
However, I found that the value does not refresh at all, whenever I want to check new value, I have to press F5.
Is it the purpose of vendor, or is the configuration in somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently there is no auto-reload function in the single view in MoSKito Inspect. MoSKito Control does support auto-reloading, but is best used if you have a cluster of web applications.

This feature was actually supported in versions prior to 2.5.x, but got removed because of low interest. If you feel, that it is an interesting and useful feature, you can always submit a ticket on projects JIRA:

https://jira.opensource.anotheria.net/browse/MSK

(or even implement it yourself and submit a pull request).

regards
Leon